# ComponentNotFoundException: Unable to find component using Filament PHP plugin

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

I am using Filament PHP and created a resource named `UserResource`. This resource is registered in the ServiceProvider of my Filament plugin:

```php
namespace musa11971\MyPlugin;

use Filament\PluginServiceProvider;
use musa11971\MyPlugin\Resources\UserResource;
use Spatie\LaravelPackageTools\Package;

class MyPluginProvider extends PluginServiceProvider
{
    protected array $resources = [
        UserResource::class
    ];

    public function configurePackage(Package $package): void
    {
        $package->name('my-plugin')
            ->hasTranslations();
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../resources/lang', 'my-plugin');
    }
}
```

All my pages/components load fine, but when I interact with the components (e.g. clicking a button), a Livewire Exception is thrown:

```
Unable to find component: [musa11971.my-plugin.resources.user-resource.pages.edit-user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call `parent::boot()` in the boot method of your Service Provider.

```php
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        
        $this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../resources/lang', 'my-plugin');
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

**try this:**

```
public function packageBooted(): void
{
   parent::packageBooted();
   
   // Do somthing...
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?